# Cast uint64 to uint32 and uint16

Tags: solidity, math

I wrote a contract to understand the difference of casting variable to uint16 and uint32. Code as below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Learning{

    bytes8 theKey = 0x3fcb875f0000ddc4;

    function cast32() public view returns (uint32) {
        return uint32(uint64(theKey));
    }

    function cast16() public view returns (uint16) {
        return uint16(uint64(theKey));
    }

}
```

After calling `cast32()` and `cast16()`, I received similar answers for both which are `56772`. Why does it give similar answers when I casted it using different uint i.e. uint16 and uint32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an explanation for this.

Notice that the last four bytes of your `theKey` are `0000ddc4`. So, we see that we have 2 bytes empty (0000) and 2 bytes with data (ddc4). A 32-bit number is 4 bytes. A 16-bit number is 2 bytes. So, when you are casting `0x3fcb875f_0000ddc4` to a `uint16`, you are copying `ddc4`. When you are casting it to a `uint32`, you are copying `0000ddc4`, and since the first 2 bytes don't have any values, both are `ddc4`. If we convert `ddc4` to decimal, it's `56772`. Check here: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

I created 2 mask values to copy the last 32 bits (4 bytes) of the number and 16 bits (2 bytes) of the same number. I created the functions `getLast16Bits` and `getLast32Bits` and they both yield the same result.

If you put more values in those empty bytes, then the result will be different.

For example, given: `0x3fcb875faaffddc4`, the result would be `65535` for the `uint16` casting, and `4294967295` for the `uint32` casting.

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Learning {

    uint32 public mask32 = 0x000000000000000000000000ffffffff;
    uint16 public mask16 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000ffff;

    bytes8 public theKey = 0x3fcb875f_0000ddc4;

    uint64 public theKey64 = uint64(theKey);

    function getLast16Bits() public view returns(uint) {
        return theKey64 & mask16;
    }

    function getLast32Bits() public view returns(uint) {
        return theKey64 & mask32;
    }

    function cast32() public view returns (uint32) {
        return uint32(uint64(theKey));
    }

    function cast16() public view returns (uint16) {
        return uint16(uint32(uint64(theKey)));
    }

}
```

Comment: That's such a clear explanation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number that fits in an uint16 is `2**16 - 1 = 65535`

Since your number is smaller than that the uint16 is not truncated.